# Segment division with given ratio

Tags: coordinate-systems

> Find the coordinates of point $P$ that divides the segment $AB$ in a ratio of $1:3$ , given that A=$(2,1)$ , B=$(6,9)$  ?

Comment: https://brilliant.org/wiki/section-formula/

Comment: have you drawn the segment on a sheet of paper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the straight line through $A,B$ has the equation $$y=2x-3$$ and additionally we have
$$\frac{\sqrt{(x-2)^2+(y-1)^2}}{\sqrt{(6-x)^2+(9-y)^2}}=\frac{1}{3}$$
Can you get it from here?

Comment: Sure , thank you very much  , the answer is  $(3,3)$